# why does heroku server does not play my mp4 video

Tags: python, html, django, heroku

here i am using Django in backend. on my local machine there is not an problem but when i upload it on Heroku  it shows all the files but  video is messing.?

```
<video width="540" autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="{% static 'home/img/Inbodyshot.mp4' %}" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Check if your video exists on heroku. You could use ```heroku run bash``` command and do a ```ls```. That will list you all the files.

Comment: Yes video is there

Comment: Can you check if ```src``` of ```<source>``` tag is pointing to your Video location ?

Comment: yes its also correct, actually its working right on local machine but as i upload it on heroku it stops working

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem it seems the video file is considered too large or the video format.
You can try serving static files on aws s3 bucket, this will work.